# Check if specific attribute present in xml file in scala?

Tags: xml, scala

I'm very very new to scala so bear with me if this seems basic.
I have the following XML file

```
<xml>
    <things/>
    <items>

        <stuff name="John"/>
        <stuff name="Jacob"/>
        <stuff name="George"/>
        <stuff name="alice"/>

    </items>    

</xml>
```

and from this file I want to see if a specific name attribute is present in a stuff tag. (ex: see if Jacob exists or see if Lisa exists within the xml file)

So far I have the following code

```
import scala.xml._
val xml = XML.loadFile("sample.xml")
val stuff = (xml \\ "stuff")
//The following val contains: scala.collection.immutable.Seq[scala.xml.MetaData] = List( name="John",  name="Jacob",  name="George",  name="alice")
val names= stuff.map(_.attributes)
```

Now I notice that this creates a List but when I use the contains method on the val names it gives me false even for a value like alice.

```
val exists= names.contains("alice")
```

produces this output in the REPL:

```
exists: Boolean = false
```

How would I test if a value is contained in this file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type for `names` is a `Seq[scala.xml.MetaData]` and you are using contains to search for the `String` "alice" which as you can see isn't going to work.

To get the text from the name attribute map each `scala.xml.MetaData` to it's text representation with `text` and you get back a `Seq[String]` which allows you to search for "alice".

```
scala> val names = (xml \\ "items" \\ "stuff" \\ "@name").map(_.text)
names: scala.collection.immutable.Seq[String] = List(John, Jacob, George, alice)

scala> names.contains("alice")
res22: Boolean = true
```

Comment: Thank you! I was stuck on this for hours yesterday